# OpenCV Background subtraction by frame averaging

Tags: c++, opencv

How do i implement background subtraction(background model obtained by averaging first..say 50 frames..) in opencv
I tried looking for some codes but found they were in python..im working in c++(visual studio 2013)
A small working code snippet will help..thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV provide background subtraction capabilities. See [BackgroundSubtractorMOG2](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#backgroundsubtractormog2), that models the background with a Mixture of Gaussians, and is therefore quite robust to background changes.

The parameters `history` is the numbers of frame used to build the background model.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int history = 50;
    float varThreshold = 16.f; // default value
    BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg = BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history, varThreshold);
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    Mat3b frame;
    Mat1b fmask;

    for (;;)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        bg(frame, fmask, -1);

        imshow("frame", frame);
        imshow("mask", fmask);
        if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break;               
    }
    return 0;
}
```